# My phone is sending out MMS messages to unknown numbers

Tags: malware, mms

My phone is sending out MMS messages without my consent to random unknown numbers and out of my contacts. The message that is sent out on my phone is as follows:

> You have received an MMS message. Read here.

Then there's an HTTP address I won't put it here, don't know what on earth it is.

I've run an anti-virus app. Can someone help me please, do I need to do a factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you have managed to install some malware - check the Application settings for those with permission to send MMS messages and disable MMS functions for any that you don't recognise or need to be able to send messages and possibly uninstall them. It is probably worth doing this periodically anyway.

If you go to Applications in the Settings area, (the gear), and select the options, (the pile of 3 dots on the top right on my version), you can select SMS to get a list of all the Apps that can send SMS, *and presumably MMS*.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had an app that actually sent any messages. I've had some that requested permission to send MMS messages but none ever did. If my device did something like yours is I'd swear it was hacked or even cloned. Whatever is going on with your phone has one simple fix. I'd reset the device to factory.